# Java OOP based Program Flow

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

i am learning basic java  , Read  basic concepts from Head First Java  (Polymorphisim,abstract  class/methods, overriding etc ) ,  now i am doing  a very simple  example   where a Remote is used for  Tv, Home Theater  and Cd Player. one remote must work for all 3 devices perfectly  .  Now what i did  is ..

- Remote is  super class of all these 3 class    Tv, Home Theater, Cd
  Player.
- Basic functions  like  on , off , volume +-, channel +-  etc are in 
  super class these are overridden
- Methods those are not common are implemented in interfaces like 
  Eject , Insert , for Cd player ,  Display settings for  TV and
  Theater etc  .

  So is this approach OK ?

> Taking one class as super class and implementing rest of the code in
>   interfaces .

Another point ,`if one method is  common in  Tv  and theater  like Display settings should i implement interface or  change my class hierarchy  .`.

Please dont  mind  if its stupid  question   , and also guide me about these oop designs techniques , Thank you

Comment: that means just a demo sir not the original remote ... just try to understand i will input for on off using boolean values .. +,- for volume .. and so taking input from BufferedReader etc  ... dont cosider i m coding it for some  original remote it has to show input and output on console .. thats it

Comment: How is a remote a super class of a TV? Is a TV a special kind of remote? :P

Comment: @Patashu  i did ignore is-A test ....that's my mistake

Comment: o i see, abstraction of real life, great.

Comment: @blackbee remote is a PERFECT example, what are you saying. When you learn you need to use a example, a real life example that you understand really well. What are you expecting that we learn using DUCK's only....

Comment: i think i said/typed great

Comment: yeah, just saw that.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TV, HomeTheater, CD Player are clearly NOT IS-A remote. They are indeed remotable. It give us a hint there should be interface `Remotable` and is implemented by devices.

```
interface Remotable {
    void turnOff();
    void turnOn();
    void volumeUp();
    void volumeDown();
    void selftDestruct();
}
```

Then we make all devices implement this interface.

```
class Television implements Remotable {

    @Override
    void turnOff() {
        System.out.println("Television is turned off");
    }

    //implements the rest.
}

class HomeTheater implements Remotable {
    // implements likes Television
}

class CDPlayer implements Remotable {
}
```

Then made a `Remote` class to handle `Remotable` devices.

```
class Remote  {
    private Remotable target;

    public Remote(Remotable target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void turnOn() {
        target.turnOn();
    }
}
```

And assemble everything, we have something like this:

```
Television tv = new Television();
Remote remote = new Remote(tv);
remote.turnOn();
```

Comment: please explain class Remote  {} this class . thank you

Comment: the `Remote` class is simply the remote. It only knows how to work with `Remotable` objects and doesn't care the object is a `Television`, `HomeTheater` or `CDPlayer`.

Comment: that clears the idea ,

Comment: so i read it 3 times and its perfect answer ..

Answer (score 7):

Before you implement Inheritance(SuperClass-SubClass logic) always do a **Is-A** test. Is Tv a Remote? No... then your approach is wrong. According to me it must be an interface. Tv must implement not extends Remote. It is not that whenever you have common code you avoid duplication using Inheritance.

Basic functions like on , off , volume +-, channel +- etc must be in Remote Interface and all other Classes TV n all must implement them.

```
public Class TV implements Remote
```

Also if you want to use Inheritance you can have a SupeClass like **ElectronicGadget**. All your  Tv, Home Theater, Cd Player are  Electronic Gadgets. You can have common methods like

```
public boolean turnOn()
public boolean turnOff()
```

in it.

Comment: one more thing i can implement all my methods in Remote interface that are common and for rest ones that are not common should i define those methods in those classes or define separate interfaces for them ? thank u

Comment: It does not work that way. It must also make sense. Like for example if you want to maintain which channels you are subscribed to then function like addChannel() or removeChannel() will not make sense in Remote interface .. you will need to define a new interface say CableConnection. Now even if you want to watch channels on your computer you can simply say computer implements CableConnection.

Comment: Instead of 'implements Remote' I'd say 'implements RemoteControllable' or something like that, but the idea is right

Answer (score 2):

Next to what have been said. You may have an abstract class called RemoteControl. In this class you implement the common methods. If you want a TV remote control you implement class called TvRemoteControl that extends RemoteControl. This way you are saying that TvRemoteControl Is-A RemoteControl.

On top of this you can add a RemoteControl to a TV object.

Does this make sense?

Comment: yes "On top of this you can add a RemoteControl to a TV object.
" what does this mean ?

Comment: I meant, if you have a class called TV you add an attribute to it of kind RemoteControl. `public class TV implement Remotable {private RemoteControl remote = new TvRemoteControl();}`

Comment: this was just what i was thinking. its clean.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand when you mean Remote is the superclass, it is for all Remote types (for TV, CD Player etc)

The behavior of remote changes from gadget to gadget. So `RemoteControl` is probably an interface having set of methods. All the implementation classes will have their flavor for it.

Note: I would suggest to add more meaningful class/interface names. I would not prefer `Remote` as it could as well mean `java.rmi.Remote` of JDK

One more thing: Prefer to add code to your superclass when you think it is reusable for all subclasses or when they do a `super.`

```
class Super
{
   public void method1()
   {
   }
}

class Sub extends Super
{
   public void method1()
   {
      super.method1();
      //Add more behavior specific to Sub
   }
}
```

Comment: your solution is the "real solution" where the remote and the TV both are conntected to the local area network, but he's just learning java basics .. so I think it's just an Object-Oriented example

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, you are missing the point.

Its about change, not about use of OOP correctly. Do you believe you are going to add more devices in future ? OR are the functions of a particular device going to change ?

If you are building a unique remote control for all devices you are going to need different types of remotes for those devices. And each device may / may not have more than 1 remote. So you cannot inherit remote properties, instead you need to implement the needed remote property that basically needed for that device. The remote itself will have a tree like structure inheriting from each other. Remotes will inherit features like channelClicker, soundBasic, soundAdvanced, soundProfessional, videoChild.

Now if you are building a universal remote then devices will change, you need to control the code change in other devices as you add new devices. So you need to abstract out device types while the remote is in function. The remote will behave differently for different devices. Some devices the remote will throw up a "not supported". While some the volume will increase 5db per upPress, and some 50db per upPress. For each device the remote parameters will be different. Unit of decibel, unit of brightness.

You have to **think** differently and design for **change**. As you change code in future you should not need to retest all the devices, all the remotes, since the change will be localized just for that device. You can have different small libraries per device, that way even if you rebuild and run tests, none of the older tests need to be run since you did not change any code.

Design patterns need to make your mind oriented towards minimal change in code **in the future**.

Edit : 
And, you have a good question. I recommend you read the first 3 chapters again, and drink a lot more water. You are very close. Dont give up, dont change your example, dont give in unless you get it. Trust me, you are very close.

Comment: Thank your sir , sure i will read first 3 ch as i m very much determined to do it :)

Comment: Read it again and again, if you get the first 3 chapters you can breeze thru the rest, trust me, you will get it. dont give up.

Comment: sure i have hard copy, i will read these  right now .